# Add Join in BQLCommand

Tags: acumatica

I would like to join the following statement with EPEmployee table on EPEmployee's BAccountID with FSAppointmentEmployee's EmployeeID column then put where condition on EPEmployee's UserID with currently logged in employee's user id in the current BQLCommand for PXAdapter, so that I can see the list of appointments that are assigned to current employee only.

```
public static PXAdapter PrepareCustomNavAdapter(PXAction action, PXAdapter adapter, bool prevNextAction = false)
        {
            var select = adapter.View.BqlSelect;
            select = select
                .WhereAnd<Where<EPEmployee.userID,Equal<AccessInfo.userID>>>()
                .OrderByNew<OrderBy<
                Desc<FSAppointment.createdDateTime,
                Desc<FSAppointment.srvOrdType,
                Desc<FSAppointment.refNbr>>>>>();

            var newAdapter = new PXAdapter(new PXView(action.Graph, true, select))
            {
                MaximumRows = adapter.MaximumRows
            };

            object current = action.Graph.Views[action.Graph.PrimaryView].Cache.Current;
            if (prevNextAction)
            {
                var sortColumns = new string[adapter.SortColumns.Count() + 1];
                adapter.SortColumns.CopyTo(sortColumns, 1);
                sortColumns[0] = "CreatedDateTime";
                newAdapter.SortColumns = sortColumns;

                var descendings = new bool[adapter.Descendings.Count() + 1];
                adapter.Descendings.CopyTo(descendings, 1);
                descendings[0] = true;
                newAdapter.Descendings = descendings;

                var searches = new object[adapter.Searches.Count() + 1];
                adapter.Searches.CopyTo(searches, 1);
                if (current != null && current is FSAppointment)
                    searches[0] = ((FSAppointment)current).CreatedDateTime;
                newAdapter.Searches = searches;
            }
            else if (current != null)
            {
                adapter.Currents = new object[] { current };
            }
            
            return newAdapter;
        }
```

[image]
So that, only these two employees would be able to see that appointment.

Thank you.

Comment: For now, because of this line:
`.WhereAnd<Where<EPEmployee.userID,Equal<AccessInfo.userID>>>()`
It prompts me 'The multi part identified <field_name> could not be bound.' for both of the fields.

Answer (score 1):

AccessInfo is a Singleton, you should decorate it with Current class:

```
Where<EPEmployee.userID, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userID>>>
```

Comment: For the missing join on EPEmployee, are you using a DataVew or BqlCommand on adapter before calling your method? I would add the join to a DataView or BqlCommand before calling the method : BqlCommand.Compose(typeof(InnerJoin<EPEmployee, On<EPEmployee.userID, Equal<SomeDac.userID>>>),

Comment: I am using BqlCommand on adapter. 
But I am still getting this error. "The multi-part identifier "EPEmployee.userID" could not be bound."
The code is in the next comment.

Comment: `var select = adapter.View.BqlSelect;
BqlCommand.Compose(typeof(InnerJoin<FSAppointmentEmployee, On<FSAppointmentEmployee.appointmentID,Equal<Current<FSAppointment.appointmentID>>>>));
BqlCommand.Compose(typeof(InnerJoin<EPEmployee,On<EPEmployee.bAccountID, Equal<FSAppointmentEmployee.employeeID>>>));            select = select          .WhereAnd<Where<EPEmployee.userID,Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userID>>>>().OrderByNew<OrderBy<
                Desc<FSAppointment.createdDateTime,
                Desc<FSAppointment.srvOrdType,
                Desc<FSAppointment.refNbr>>>>>();`

Comment: Then, I add edit this line to:  .WhereAnd<Where<EPEmployee.userID,Equal<Current<AccessInfo.u‌​serID>>>>()
this
.WhereAnd<Where<Current<EPEmployee.userID>,Equal<Current<AccessInfo.u‌​serID>>>>()
which I believe is not right, but still gave a try. I didn't prompt me error but I was able to see appointments which are not assigned to me.

Comment: From your code, it seems you're not using the return value of BQLComand.Compose.

Comment: I tried to return the value using the code below:
`var select = adapter.View.BqlSelect;
var filter1= typeof(InnerJoin<FSAppointmentEmployee,On<FSAppointmentEmployee.appointmentID, Equal<Current<FSAppointment.appointmentID>>>>);            var filter2 = typeof(InnerJoin<EPEmployee,On<EPEmployee.bAccountID,Equal<FSAppointmentEmployee.employeeID>>>);
var filter3 = typeof(Where<EPEmployee.userID,Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userID>>>);
var filter4 = typeof(OrderBy<           Desc<FSAppointment.createdDateTime,             Desc<FSAppointment.srvOrdType,              Desc<FSAppointment.refNbr>>>>);`

Comment: `select = BqlCommand.CreateInstance(BqlCommand.Compose(select.GetType(), filter1, filter2, filter3, filter4));`

But, I get the error saying as follow: The parameter length exceeds the allowed value. Now, is there anyway I can just add the current employee filter on appointment's list?

Comment: You can add the current login employee with AccessInfo using the Current class but for EPEmployee you do need to compose a valid query with Select and Join clauses to select records from that table. You can also try BqlCommand.AppendJoin but I think your problem is deeper than that, the way you use BQL.Compose is different from the examples I see in Acumatica code base.

Comment: Hi!
I have updated the code like this now.
http://www.screencast.com/t/7Py6m8moU
But still, it is now showing appointments correctly. Is there anything wrong in the BQL construction?